# Microsoft SQL server CASE ELSE CASE not closing right

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm writing the beginnings of an SP for sql server using a few case statements and temp tables with a conditional case else statement at the end to subtract values from each other based on the conditional case else statement.

It's all working fine until I get to the conditional case else statement where for some reason the END isn't close right.

As you can see from the conditional case else statement there is only one syntax error at the bracket after the END.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
--Creates a temp table to store the results of the cases below ans inserts them into the table.
CREATE TABLE #TotalBySlSsCs(

    BoughtTotal FLOAT  NULL,
    SoldTotal FLOAT  NULL,
    SSaleTotal FLOAT  NULL,
    CShortTotal FLOAT  NULL,
    TotalQuanity Float NULL
) 

INSERT INTO #TotalBySlSsCs(BoughtTotal, SoldTotal, SSaleTotal, CShortTotal)

 -- Cases to total the quanities for portfilios and securities based on the transcode is in ('by', 'sl', 'ss', 'cs') plus the portfolio, security, and date selected by the user.
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN FundTransactions.TransCode='by' THEN (CAST(FundTransactions.Quantity AS FLOAT)) ELSE 0 END) AS 'BoughtTotal',
    SUM(CASE WHEN FundTransactions.TransCode='sl' THEN (CAST(FundTransactions.Quantity AS FLOAT)) ELSE 0 END) AS 'SoldTotal',
    SUM(CASE WHEN FundTransactions.TransCode='ss' THEN (CAST(FundTransactions.Quantity AS FLOAT)) ELSE 0 END) AS 'SSaleTotal',  
    SUM(CASE WHEN FundTransactions.TransCode='cs' THEN (CAST(FundTransactions.Quantity AS FLOAT)) ELSE 0 END) AS 'CShortTotal'

FROM FundTransactions
--The Where section will contain @parameters to let users select the portfolio, security, and date they need.
WHERE FundTransactions.PortfolioCode = 'EFS' AND FundTransactions.SecSymbol = 'VXX' AND FundTransactions.TradeDate= '2014-06-30'
GROUP BY FundTransactions.TransCode

--Group on Total Quanity to remove the second uneeded row which is created by the above cases and inserts it into temp table #TotalQuanities for calculations..
CREATE TABLE #TotalQuanities(
    TotalQuanity VARCHAR(4) NULL,
    TotalBy FLOAT  NULL,
    TotalSl FLOAT  NULL,
    TotalSs FLOAT  NULL,
    TotalCs FLOAT  NULL
) 

INSERT INTO #TotalQuanities(TotalQuanity, TotalBy, TotalSl, TotalSs, TotalCs)

SELECT #TotalBySlSsCs.TotalQuanity, MAX(#TotalBySlSsCs.BoughtTotal), MAX(#TotalBySlSsCs.SoldTotal), MAX(#TotalBySlSsCs.SSaleTotal), MAX(#TotalBySlSsCs.CShortTotal)

FROM #TotalBySlSsCs
GROUP BY #TotalBySlSsCs.TotalQuanity

--Case statement for subtracting the final figures from each other based on conditions within the case statement.
SELECT #TotalQuanities.TotalQuanity, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN #TotalQuanities.TotalBy = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSl = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSs = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalCs = 0 
        THEN 0  

        ELSE

        CASE WHEN #TotalQuanities.TotalBy != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSl != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSs != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalCs != 0 
        THEN  #TotalQuanities.TotalBy - #TotalQuanities.TotalSl - #TotalQuanities.TotalSs - #TotalQuanities.TotalCs 

        ELSE

        CASE WHEN #TotalQuanities.TotalBy = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSl != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSs != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalCs != 0 
        THEN #TotalQuanities.TotalSl - #TotalQuanities.TotalSs - #TotalQuanities.TotalCs 

        ELSE 

        CASE WHEN #TotalQuanities.TotalBy = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSl = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSs != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalCs != 0 
        THEN #TotalQuanities.TotalSs - #TotalQuanities.TotalCs  

        ELSE

        CASE WHEN #TotalQuanities.TotalBy = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSl = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSs = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalCs != 0 
        THEN #TotalQuanities.TotalCs

        END) AS 'TOTAL'


FROM #TotalQuanities
GROUP BY #TotalQuanities.TotalQuanity

--Drops the temp tables.
DROP TABLE #TotalBySlSsCs
DROP TABLE #TotalQuanities
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't repeat `case` in case statements for multiple conditions.  Try this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN #TotalQuanities.TotalBy = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSl = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSs = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalCs = 0 
    THEN 0  

    WHEN #TotalQuanities.TotalBy != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSl != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSs != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalCs != 0 
    THEN  #TotalQuanities.TotalBy - #TotalQuanities.TotalSl - #TotalQuanities.TotalSs - #TotalQuanities.TotalCs 

    WHEN #TotalQuanities.TotalBy = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSl != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSs != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalCs != 0 
    THEN #TotalQuanities.TotalSl - #TotalQuanities.TotalSs - #TotalQuanities.TotalCs 

    WHEN #TotalQuanities.TotalBy = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSl = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSs != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalCs != 0 
    THEN #TotalQuanities.TotalSs - #TotalQuanities.TotalCs  

    WHEN #TotalQuanities.TotalBy = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSl = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSs = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalCs != 0 
    THEN #TotalQuanities.TotalCs

    END) AS TOTAL
```

Also, you shouldn't use single quotes for column or table aliases, but that is another matter.

Comment: Thanks for the help Gordon, appreciate it. Also very good point about the single quotes. Laziness on my part.

Answer (score 1):

replace the case with below

```
SELECT #TotalQuanities.TotalQuanity, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN #TotalQuanities.TotalBy = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSl = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSs = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalCs = 0 
        THEN 0  
       WHEN #TotalQuanities.TotalBy != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSl != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSs != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalCs != 0 
        THEN  #TotalQuanities.TotalBy - #TotalQuanities.TotalSl - #TotalQuanities.TotalSs - #TotalQuanities.TotalCs 
       WHEN #TotalQuanities.TotalBy = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSl != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSs != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalCs != 0 
        THEN #TotalQuanities.TotalSl - #TotalQuanities.TotalSs - #TotalQuanities.TotalCs 
       WHEN #TotalQuanities.TotalBy = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSl = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSs != 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalCs != 0 
        THEN #TotalQuanities.TotalSs - #TotalQuanities.TotalCs  
       WHEN #TotalQuanities.TotalBy = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSl = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalSs = 0 AND #TotalQuanities.TotalCs != 0 
        THEN #TotalQuanities.TotalCs

        END) AS 'TOTAL'
FROM #TotalQuanities
GROUP BY #TotalQuanities.TotalQuanity
```